# What methods are available for looking up a character?

Tags: dictionary, character-identification, radicals

Some dictionaries provide a radical lookup for finding characters. Are there other systems available *besides* radical lookup for finding the meaning of a word when one only has the character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question could probably best be answered [by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_input_method) as there are many, many methods.

One relatively common one is to look up the character [by stroke count, then by stroke order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_count_method). In this system, there are five types of strokes and each is assigned a number.

```
+--------+------------------------------+
| Number | Stroke type                  |
+--------+------------------------------+
|      1 | Horizontal, or rising        |
|      2 | Vertical                     |
|      3 | Falling to the Left          |
|      4 | Dot, or Falling to the Right |
|      5 | Turning                      |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

This is the method used to look up characters in 现代汉语通用字笔顺规范, the official character stroke order reference in mainland China. For example, below is the character 永 in this book:

[image]

If you want to look up this character, you will first go to the page with the 5-strokes characters, then you would search for the dot stroke (4), then the hook (5), etc. Basically, its code would be 45534.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite online dictionary, **[Nciku](http://www.nciku.com/)** lets you draw in a character, and then tells you what it is. Super useful if you can't find out what the radical is, or just want a quicker way to look something out.

My favorite iOS app, **[Pleco](http://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/pleco-chinese-dictionary/id341922306?mt=8)** has this functionality, along with Optical Character Recognition (OCR) so you can hold up/take pictures of one or more Characters, and it will then give you the definitions of them. It's pretty cool.

Are these the sort of things you mean?

Comment: Yes, but also, perhaps some kinds that are used in books.

Answer (score 2):

You can just search it by www.baidu.com which can input character by drawing or search it by any search engine with Chinese input method supporting drawing.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Wiktionary to look up a word if you know the pronunciation and the meaning but you don't know the character.

Example: [ye4](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ye4#Mandarin)

I also quite frequently use [Google HK](http://www.google.com.hk/) to perform a search, which is useful for when you have a sentence, and type in something like shanshuihua, it will provide you a list of options in Chinese.

Comment: the OP asked for resources in situations where *only the character* can be used to look something up.